# Downloading pdf file from Cloudinary using link in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, cloudinary

I want to download a pdf file from Cloudinary by clicking a link. I`ve tried the "download" attribute of the anchor tag as well as taget="_blank". When the link opens it gives 404 Error. Can I make a downloadable link from Cloudinary or by using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the 404 - Most likely that's due to a restriction on Cloudinary that was introduced earlier in the year that prevents downloads of PDF/Archive files (.zip, .rar etc) by default on new Free accounts. That restriction can be removed for your account and you should contact Cloudinary support for this. More information:
https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016480179-Why-does-my-pdf-link-isn-t-working-

In terms of achieving the 'download' functionality - You can add the Cloudinary flags => attachment [transformation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/transformation_reference#fl_attachment) (`fl_attachment in URLs`) and that will set the `Content-Disposition` header with value 'attachment' and the file will download.

```
<a href="https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/fl_attachment/sample.jpg">Download</a>
```